# How to display the value from 2 tables with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

Table1

```
ID date value

001 23/01/2012 100
002 25/02/2012 200
....
```

Table2

```
Id date value

001 01/01/2012 200
001 02/01/2012 100
...
001 23/02/2012 200
...
001 31/03/2012 100
002 ....
.....
```

I want to select the table2 value, if id and date is matching with table1 then value will display from table1

Id date value

```
001 01/01/2012 200
001 02/01/2012 100
...
001 23/02/2012 100 'matching id and date from table1
...
001 31/03/2012 100
002 ....
.....
```

How to do this.

Need query help

Expected Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table2.ID, Table2.date,
            CASE
                WHEN Table1.ID = Table2.ID
                     AND Table1.date = Table2.date THEN Table1.value
                ELSE Table2.value
            END
FROM Table1, Table2
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT n_t.n_ID,
       n_t.n_date,
       n_t.n_value
FROM
  (SELECT Table2.ID AS n_ID,
          Table2.date AS n_date,
          CASE
              WHEN Table1.ID = Table2.ID THEN CASE
                                                  WHEN Table1.date = Table2.date THEN Table1.value
                                                  ELSE Table2.value
                                              END
          END AS n_value
   FROM Table1,
        Table2) AS n_t
WHERE n_t.n_value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I think first on give some duplicates but the edited query works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there's never more than one row in table1 with the same id and date as a row in table2 (e.g. if id/date is a unique/primary key of table1) then the following will work:

```
SELECT
    table2.id,
    table2.date,
    ISNULL(table1.value, table2.value) AS value
FROM table2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON table2.id = table1.id
        AND table2.date = table1.date
```

If more than one row from table1 may match a row in table2 then you'll need to aggregate and decide which of the distinct values to use, or if you want to take an average, minimum, or maximum.